# Using winforms to develop a software

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, sql-server-express

Is Winforms the only way to develop the GUI of a software?

The software would use SQL Server Express edition & would be built on C#.NET

EDIT: The software would run on LAN over a single or multiple systems locally. In case of multiple systems SQL SERVER would be installed only on ONE PC and the others would connect to it. Also, all systems would have Windows XP or 7.

Comment: There are several options available Winforms, WPF, Web apps,silverlight etc. It all depends on your requirements like where do you want to run the software, what kinda usage and several other factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

today more preferred technology is WPF which allows you to design application in more maintainable and testable way. But depends what system are you targeting in terms of WPF / NET availability

Additionally you can consider SQL compact as an alternative to SQL express

Comment: so is it inbuilt in visual studio , how shall i start, what to download

Comment: you can get some directions here: http://windowsclient.net/getstarted/ notice the 'Essential downloads' on that page

Answer (score 3):

or SilverLight  is another option as that seems to be growing in support over WPF

you can use it as an in browser or out of browser technology

Answer (score 2):

No, no they're not...

(assuming desktop software, you can use WPF or silverlight, although others like [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) are available.)

Answer (score 2):

There is also [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) for desktop based GUI on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's never an "only way" to develop something.  Your most immediate options are:

- WinForms
- WPF
- Silverlight
- (any web technology, if you want)

There are lots of less obvious ones, if you're feeling adventurous.  (They generally involve stepping outside the Microsoft stack, which you may or may not want to do at this point.)

Given today's trends, it's likely that you'll want to use WPF for a basic Windows application.  Though there are other factors to go into this decision.  If, for example, your application needs to run on a whole variety of target systems, WPF may not be supported on all of them.